# jQuery bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to jQuery and I have installed a bootstrap for JavaScript, for dropdown using.

I have followed all the tutorials but I cannot make it work. 
I am using the dropdown in a button inside a widget (chatbox), and idk how to handle with that, I have spent more than 2 hours testing but got no results.

Here's the part of my code that I am using to create the dropdown:

```
uiChatboxTitlebarSettings = (self.uiChatboxTitlebarSettings = $('<div class="dropdown"></div>'))
.append('<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>')
.addClass('ui-corner-all ' + 'ui-chatbox-icon2')
.attr('role', 'button')
.hover(function() {
    uiChatboxTitlebarSettings.addClass('ui-state-hover');
},
    function() {
        uiChatboxTitlebarSettings.removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    })
.click(function(event) {
    uiChatboxTitlebarSettings.dropdown();
    return false;
})
.on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    alert('dropdown created');
})
.appendTo(uiChatboxTitlebar),
uiChatboxSettingsDropdown = (self.uiChatboxSettingsDropdown = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu"  role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"></ul>'))
.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="tab">Texto 1</span></a></li>')
.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="tab">Texto 2</span></a></li>')
.append('<li><a href="#"><span class="tab">Texto 3</span></a></li>')
.appendTo(uiChatboxTitlebarSettings),
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using this in a widget, using jQueryUI and jQueryChatbox.

Screenshot, the dropdown is called by gear icon

[image]

Comment: can you put this into a codepen or jsbin. It is hard to tell what related resources are affecting you. Did you modify that actual bootstrap files?

Comment: I don't have any modified files in bootstrap. I'm using jQuery, jQueryUI, jQueryChatboxWidget and the Bootstrap. I think it'll be hard to put on jsbin by the widget.

Comment: ^ it is actually extremely simple to add any of those resources. Just link to them from CDNJS, which I help maintain ;) see this blog post  to help you out: [Adding External Resources](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/adding-external-resources/)